# Change the Nth field of a CSV file according to Xth field string

Tags: bash

My file looks like:

```
invoice;123;456
invoice;789;012
total;912;468
```

I need to "if first field starts by "total", then put zero in third field", so I can get:

```
invoice;123;456
invoice;789;012
total;912;0
```

I am familiar with sed sintax, but using fields is far from my posibilities. Probably awk is more convenient...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk  'BEGIN {FS = ";"; OFS=";"; } $1 ~ /^total/ { $3 = 0 } 1'
```

`FS` is the input field separator, `OFS` is the output field separator.

`$1` is the first field, we check if it begins with `total`; if so, we set the third field to 0.

`1` is always true, it causes the line to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

sed solution

```
sed -e 's/\(total;[0-9]\+;\)[0-9]*\(;*\)/\10\2/g' <file>
```

instead of `-e`, `-i` will change the file itself.

Whatever is inside first set of `\(...)\` is actually the first field and it gets replaced at `\1`, then `[0-9]*` is any number, which is replaced by `0`, then in last `\(;*\)` means if any other field is present, put it in place of `\2`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` solution

```
sed -i 's/\(^total;.*;\)\(.*\)/\10/g' file

(^total;.*;)(.*) -> (First group matches until the second semicolon)(Second group matches rest)
\10 -> Replacement is \1 (first group) + 0 (zero)
```